# Will I be able to use C# 4 as my scripting language?

Tags: ironpython, c#-4.0

In one of my C# application I use IronPython as a script language.  It looks something like this:

```
string scriptCode = "20 * 5";
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source =
  engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(scriptCode , SourceCodeKind.Expression);
Console.WriteLine(source.Execute<int>());
```

Will I be able to do something similar with C# 4.0?  Can I use C# as my scripting language instead of IronPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - not out of the box, anyway. C# itself isn't becoming a scripting language, at the moment anyway. The C# team [*are* considering that scenario in general though](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/24/it-already-is-a-scripting-language.aspx).

(That post talks about C# already being a scripting language - in certain scenarios.)

The [preceding post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) is equally relevant, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Is perhaps [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) what you're looking for?

Regards,

Sebastiaan